# Updating buffer content from another buffer

Tags: buffers, functions

I want to update one buffer content from another buffer periodically, for this I need to delete all lines from the target buffer firstly, then to write new lines to it. The number of lines are varying, so the extra lines which are left from the previous update should be deleted.

At this moment I found two ways to solve this task, but both are not ideal.

**First**

```
function! Buffer_update()
    " Buffer information saving
    let l:save_cur_pos = getcurpos()
    let l:save_buf_nr = bufnr('%')

    " Moving to the target buffer and cleaning its content
    buffer one 
    silent %d _

    " Simulation of the varying number of lines
    for l:num in range(system('echo $((RANDOM % 10 + 1))'))
        call setbufline('one', l:num, 'hello')
    endfor

    " Buffer information restoring
    execute 'buffer' . l:save_buf_nr
    call setpos('.', l:save_cur_pos)
endfunction
```

**Result** (buffer one)

[image]

**Drawback:** I don't like switching between buffers to achieving a desired result. It can be solved without switching, like in the second variant, but there is some problem too. It will be perfect to have `delbufline()` function like `setbufline()`, but I didn't find such one.

---

**Second**

```
function! Buffer_update()
    " Simulation of the varying number of lines
    for l:num in range(system('echo $((RANDOM % 10 + 1))'))
        call setbufline('one', l:num, 'hello')
    endfor

    " Deleting of extra lines from the previous update
    while l:num <= len(getbufline('one', 1, '$'))
        call setbufline('one', l:num, '')
        let l:num += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

**Result** (buffer one)

[image]

**Drawback:** This solution leaves blank lines. In other words, it doesn't delete lines, just makes them empty.

**The questions:**

1. Does some `delbufline()` function exist, similar to `setbufline()`?
2. Maybe someone can suggest more suitable solution, without aforementioned drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called `deletebufline()`

```
let l:bufnr = bufnr('thatbuf')
if l:bufnr != -1
    silent call deletebufline(l:bufnr, 1, '$')
    call setbufline(l:bufnr, 1, GetListOfLines())
endif
```

UPD. `deletebufline()` was added in Vim 8.1.0039

Comment: I don't have such function: *"E149: Sorry, no help for deletebufline()
"*. My vim version is 8.0

Comment: @MiniMax Update your Vim installation

Comment: what is the `silent` for?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt If the buffer was empty then `deletebufline()` prints "No lines in buffer".

Comment: @Matt ah thanks.